# Python3: модуль для работы с LDAP (AD) с аутентификацией

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо подключиться к AD и вытаскивать информацию через Python3. Для python2 есть python_ldap (все в порядке), но он не поддерживает python3. python3_ldap (так называемый LDAP3) - совершенно другой проект, который не может пройти проверку подлинности с помощью GSSAPI (Kerberos). На GitHub, вы можете найти скрипт якобы работающий в сочетании с последним модулем python_gssapi, но на сайте нерабочий пример.

**Задача: *подключиться к (AD) и брать от туда информацию с помощью Python 3.***

**Проблемы: *Я не могу найти подходящую библиотеку для Python 3. Я не могу найти примеры Python 3 для решения этой проблемы.***

Пожалуйста, помогите найти решение этой  задачи.

Answer (score 3):

Есть новая библиотека для реализации GSSAPI [Используйте ее](https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi)

Пример реализации HTTP клиентской части.

```
import base64
import gssapi
import requests
import socket


FQDN = socket.getfqdn()

# формируем принципал сервера
server_pcl = gssapi.Name('HTTP@' + FQDN, name_type=gssapi.NameType.hostbased_service)

# получаем токен сервера
server_name = gssapi.Name(server_pcl, name_type=gssapi.NameType.hostbased_service)
client_ctx = gssapi.SecurityContext(name=server_name, usage='initiate')

byte_token = client_ctx.step()  # b'\x82\x02\xab\x06'
token_64 = base64.b64encode(byte_token)
token = token_64.decode('utf-8')
# формируем заголовок для авторизации
header = {'Authorization': 'Negotiate ' + token}
# отправляем http-запрос
r = requests.post(url=resource, headers=header, data=data)
```

Полная документация библиотеки [здесь](https://pythongssapi.github.io/python-gssapi/stable/index.html)

Comment: День добрый. А можете в ответ добавить небольшой пример кода по использованию библиотеки?

Comment: добавил небольшой пример